# Selenium webdriver in web_view with Android Studio

Tags: selenium, android-studio, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium

I have produced myself java exit with selenium ide extension. Normally i have done a lot things appium with real device with java-eclipse.
 But now, I'am using a android project and i have a web_view on my app. I don't wanna  start chrome app  except of my app. My purpose, "driver" should be able to work. 
That's why, i need to trigger this web_view in android std.
(Note: I added selenium-java-3.141.59 libraries and Jar files libraries)

As give an example:

```
WebDriver  driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:?????/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            
            driver.get("https://tr-tr.blablala.com/");
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("dasdasd");
```